# VBA - Dynamic created combo-box working on one form but not other, class module issue?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Hello & Thank you for having a read:
This is a cross post from OZGRID: https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/index.php?thread/1227932-dynamic-created-combo-box-working-on-one-form-but-not-other-class-module-issue/
I have had no luck there yet, will update as soon as resolved here or there.

I have two forms with dynamically created comboboxes attempting to reference the same class module.

The first works as expected and I cannot see the problem with my code on the new form.

The Class module code is here:

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents m_ComboBoxEvents As MSForms.ComboBox
Public Property Set Box(RHS As MSForms.ComboBox)
Set m_ComboBoxEvents = RHS
End Property
Private Sub m_ComboBoxEvents_Change()
If REACTIONS.Visible = True Then
Debug.Print "hELlO"
'\\ WHEN COMBOBOX CHANGES ON REACTION FORM IT PASSES THE CAPTION INFORMATION FOR THE BUTTONS.
If Len(Box.Name) = 7 Then REACTIONS.Frame20.Controls("MyNCBtn" & Right(Box.Name, 1)).Caption = Box.List(Box.ListIndex, 1) ' will only work until 9
If Len(Box.Name) = 8 Then REACTIONS.Frame20.Controls("MyNCBtn" & Right(Box.Name, 2)).Caption = Box.List(Box.ListIndex, 1) ' will work until 99
End If
Debug.Print "Hi"
If UFSTDRDS.Visible = True Then
MsgBox ("Hello")
End If
End Sub
Public Property Get Box() As MSForms.ComboBox
Set Box = m_ComboBoxEvents
End Property
```

The form code is here.

```
Sub Not_Working()
Dim clsComboBox As New cComboBox
Dim MyCBx As MSForms.ComboBox
Dim m_colComboBoxEvents As Collection ' If I remove this line I get variable undefined error in next line, but it is not required in the working code above
Set m_colComboBoxEvents = New Collection
Loop starts here
Set MyCBx = Me.MultiPage1.Pages(2).Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1", "MyNCBox" & x, 1)
Dim MyCBxfill As Variant
MyCBxfill = ws1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
With MyCBx
.Top = 280 + ((x - 1) * 30)
.Left = 250
.Width = 350
.Height = 20
.FontSize = 8
.FontName = "Times New Roman"
.ColumnCount = UBound(MyCBxfill, 2)
'.ColumnWidths = ",0"
.List = MyCBxfill
End With
Set clsComboBox = New cComboBox
Set clsComboBox.Box = MyCBx
m_colComboBoxEvents.Add clsComboBox, CStr(m_colComboBoxEvents.Count + 1)
Loop ends here
End Sub
```

There is an example called test.xlsb if you scroll though on the ozgrid site (NB there have been a couple of text exchanges but no-one has provided any solution yet), there is also more detail there but I think I included too much detail on that post. for some reason the class is not working for me.

I do not mind a completely new approach, or alternative syntax. I am just unable to work out why it works in the original context and not the new context

Any insight and improvement to the existing code would be appreciated.

Regards

Justin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by Rory @ Ozgrid.com as detailed below:

I haven't looked at your workbook, but the declaration of your collection in the second code is in the wrong place. This line:

```
Dim m_colComboBoxEvents As Collection
```

needs to be at the module level. Otherwise, as soon as your routine finishes, the variable is cleared and there are no instances of your class left.